# How to fix Range on jQuery-UI slider and trigger function on hange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a basic form that calculates an estimated price based on quantity and one of three options. Then I tried to add a jQuery-UI slider. I need the slider to use the same values as the SELECT, in this case 10-100 but instead it seems to be using 19-109. This means I can't select the lowest value at all without using the SELECT and the max is right off the scale. I also need it to trigger my setAmount() function on slider change to update the price. I thought these would be easy to resolve but I'm still learning. I've included a jsfiddle and would be very appreciative if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Current Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $( "#quantity" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
      min: 10,
      max: 100,
      range: "min",
      value: select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
      }
    });
    $( "#quantity" ).on( "change", function() {
      slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
    });

    $('.containing-element').children().on("change", function () {setAmount();});
    $("#quantity").on("change", function () {setAmount();});
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Bestrafung/2cwp9ud6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are getting incorrect behavior by using the `selectedIndex` from the `#quantity` select.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $( "#quantity" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 10,
        min: 10,
        max: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            select.val( ui.value );
        },
        change: function(event, ui){
            setAmount();
        }
    });

    $('.containing-element').children().on("change", function () {
        setAmount();
    });

    select.on("change", function () {
        setAmount();
        slider.slider( "value", select.val() );
    });

function setAmount(){
    var a =  select.val();

    if (a <= 10){var q = 9.50}
    else if (a > 10 && a <= 20){var q = 7.5}
    else if (a > 20 && a <= 50){var q = 4.25}
    else if (a > 50 && a <= 100){var q = 2.50}

    if ($("#flip-min").val() == "noback") {$("#amount").val((a*q).toFixed(2));}
    if ($("#flip-min").val() == "hookback") {$("#amount").val((a*(q+.5)).toFixed(2));}
    if ($("#flip-min").val() == "stickyback") {$("#amount").val((a*(q+.6)).toFixed(2));}
  }
});
```

This should correct the behavior by using ui.value and modifying the select.

Comment: You're awesome, that was copy/pasted from the demo site so I blame their code. Anyway, if anyone else does something similar, I made one change. @teh-soto answer works but the setAmount() doesn't fire until the slider handle is released. I wanted it to fire as the slider was moving. Check my JSFiddle for the update: https://jsfiddle.net/Bestrafung/2cwp9ud6/7/

Comment: I actually just found another bug if anyone can help. When you select the quantity from the SELECT it doesn't line up properly. For example, if you use the slider 100 is all the way to the right, but if you select 100 it's only 90% to the right. Any ideas?

Comment: change `slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );` for `slider.slider( "value", select.val() );` in the `"change"` event for the select. Just edited the answer.